# How to pass an array in a redirect

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to pass an array in a redirect

```
 $qtedispo = array($x,$c,$s);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('demandeveh_afficherConf',array('qte'=>$qtedispo));
```

but when i try to call that array in twig

```
{%for q in qte %}
{{qte[0]}}
{%endfor%}
```

it tells me that the variable qte is unknown. Any help please?

Comment: second parameter of generateUrl() function adds REQUEST parameters to the URL. In controller responsible for handling this URL you need to take these request parameters and export them to twig template to be able to use them in template.

Comment: @Eya Behi can you show twig template?

Comment: You can use the flashbag for this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an HTTP redirection with an array as parameter.

If the route (on which you are making the redirection) is waiting for an argument (e.g. `function afficherConf(array $qte)`), you have to go into and pass the `$qte` parameter to the rendered template.

For instance:

```
// _controller part of to route "demandeveh_afficherConf"
public function afficherConfAction(array $qte)
{
    // ...

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Demandeveh:afficherConf.html.twig', array('qte' => $qte));

}
```

Then in the template ("afficherConf.html.twig" for this example), you should be able to do:

```
{% for q in qte %}
    {{ q }}
{% endfor %}
```

Depending on the number of dimensions of your `$qte` var.

**Note:**
You should have a look at [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).